# Calling a C# method that accepts byte[] with unmanaged IntPtr

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli, marshalling

My program consists of 3 components
1) C# frontend
2) C++/CLI wrapper
3) C++ backend

The C# FE contains a method that communicates with the web by getting a `Stream` from `HttpWebRequest` class. This method is being passed via the wrapper to the C++ backend, which calls it when it has new bytes to send.

```
C#  
void WriteBytes(IntPtr pBody, int cbBody); // Marshal.Copy'es the data from
     IntPtr to managed byte[], then calls Stream.WriteBytes(byte[], ...)

C++/CLI
void WriteBytes(System::IntPtr pBody, int cbBody); // uses
     Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate

C++
void WriteBytes(const BYTE* pBody, size_t cbBody); // calls function pointer 
    received from the wrapper
```

I would like to optimize this to not copy bytes from unmanaged BYTE* to managed byte[], as I control the memory allocation of all stages.
Is this possible?
Should it improve performance?

Comment: Anyone...? This is really important.

Comment: Yes avoiding copies can help performance. If you control memory allocation, use a managed byte [] to begin with and pass a pointer to the pinned array to the native code.

Comment: Also,  C++CLI eliminates the need for GetFunctionPointerForDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an arbitrary buffer into an `array<Byte>`, but you can pin the `array<Byte>` and get an unmanaged pointer to its first element, valid until the object is unpinned.

See the `pin_ptr<>` class for `C++/CLI` and the `GCHandle` class if you want to do it from C#.